# $ \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i =5 $, and $ \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i^2 =6.1 $ ; Find the largest value of these ten numbers

Tags: summation, contest-math, average

> Ten non-negative numbers are such that  $ \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i =5 $,
> and $ \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i^2 =6.1 $. What is the greatest value of the
> largest of these numbers?

It presents a lot of confusion to me, but I think the largest number maybe a integer. Please help me with procedure.

Source : Moscow Institute of Physics and Technology admission assessment for computer Science

Comment: No idea how to obtain the answer for this, but the largest number is not an integer. We could have for example one $2.3$ and nine $0.3$. As $\sqrt{6.1}\approx 2.47$, the answer should lie in the interval $[2.3, 2.47)$.

Comment: @Crevious Hi. You are a good contributor to the site, and I've seen your recent history of asking questions, but this particular question falls under the bracket of what we call a PSQ, or a problem statement question, where apart from stating the problem you haven't written much else. Remember, anything you can mention is useful : which textbook you are using, which exam/subject are you studying for, and if you are using a particular book to study and found this problem there. Your previous questions have been good. Please edit this question, otherwise it may be closed if it stays like this.

Comment: @Crevious If you have done it, kindly drop a message [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119549/teresa-lisbon-senior-agent-cbi) so I can take a look and provide feedback. You can also ask me why I am being so particular over there as well.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yeah, I can understand the fact. I will do it from next time. Mainly I am practicing those math and ask if I can't solve. Most of them are training for IMO and Cambridge mathematics admission test training. I am asking now, and I'll answer the question when I will feel that I really can.

Comment: @Crevious Thank you for the response. Please make sure that you mention at least those two things. Other things you can mention are if you have seen similar questions either on the site or among questions you have solved before. Even if this question does not improve, I will expect better from the next one. I do like the answer, though.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon  I will try my best if it is known to me, or  I can find it through google  ('-') !!!!

Comment: @Crevious To the best of your ability, is enough. Participating in comments just after posting your question gives you some credibility as well. In fact, seeing what people ask you will tell you what context is needed sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A General Problem

Suppose
$$
\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i}{n} = a
$$
and
$$
\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2}{n} = b^2
$$
Set $y_i = x_i - a$. Then (as you can check)
$$
\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i}{n} = 0
$$
So
$$
b^2 = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i + a)^2}{n} = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n  y_i^2 + 2ay_i + a^2}{n} = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2}{n} + 2a \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i}{n} + \frac{a^2}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n 1
$$
Setting
$$
c^2 = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2}{n}
$$
We obtain
$$
b^2 = c^2 + 2a(0) + a^2
$$
So
$$
c^2 = b^2 - a^2
$$
Observe that the largest $y_i$ occurs at the same index as the largest $x_i$.

The upshot of all of this is that we've reduced the problem to finding the largest possible value of a sequence of numbers $y_i$ with a mean of $0$ (i.e. $\frac{\sum_{i =1}^n y_i}{n} = 0$) and variance of $c^2$ (i.e. $\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2}{n} = c^2$).

Intuitively, it's clear that the maximum should occur when $y_1 = \ldots = y_{n -1} = y$. Applying the mean and variance condition and performing a straightforward calculation yields $y_n = \sqrt{n - 1} c$. It remains to check that this is the best we can do.

Suppose for contradiction $y_n > \sqrt{n - 1} c$. Then
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} y_i = -y_n
$$
and
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} y_i^2 = nc^2 - y_n^2
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{\sum_{i =1}^{n - 1} y_i}{n -1} = -\frac{y_n}{n - 1}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} y_i^2}{n - 1} = \frac{nc^2 - y_n^2}{n - 1}
$$
Set $z_i = y_i + \frac{y_n}{n - 1}$. Then
\begin{align}
0 &\leq \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} z_i^2}{n - 1} = \frac{nc^2 - y_n^2}{n - 1} - \left(\frac{y_n}{n - 1}\right)^2 
\\&< \frac{nc^2 - (n - 1)c^2}{n -1} - \frac{(n - 1)c^2}{(n - 1)^2} = 0
\end{align}
which is absurd. Thus $y_n = \sqrt{n - 1} c$ is the best we can do.

In terms of $x_n$, $a$, and $b$ this is
$$
x_n = a + \sqrt{(n - 1)(b^2 - a^2)}
$$

### Your Problem

In your problem $a = .5$ and $b^2 = .61$. Plugging in, you find that
$$
x_n = 2.3
$$
is the best you can do.

Comment: Interestingly, this problem has a really straightforward physical interpretation. For a given moment of inertia and set of equal masses, how far from a balanced (mean = 0) axis of rotation can I place a mass? This explains why, for example, the devices they use to spin around astronauts look the way they do: a big counterweight near the axis of rotation and a spindly arm out to the astronaut.

Comment: This is also known as [Samuelson's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuelson%27s_inequality).

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth So glad someone found it. I knew it had to be a standard result, I was just failing at Google. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 4):

Just apply [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) or [AM-QM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities) inequality to the nine smaller numbers, you get
(WLOG assume $x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots \le x_{10}$)

$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^9 x_i\right)^2 \le 9 \left( \sum_{i=1}^9 x_i^2\right)\\
\iff
(5-x_{10})^2 \le 9(6.1-x_{10}^2) \\
\iff 10x_{10}^2 - 10x_{10} - 29.9 \le 0 \\
\implies x_{10} \le 2.3.\blacksquare$$

Comment: Can you broadly explain it and it will be helpful for everyone.

Comment: @Crevious See my edit please.